# create correlation-matrix-like data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with correlation values for `A` and `B`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['A','A','B','B'],'y':['A','B','A','B'],'c':[1,0.5,0.5,1]})
```

I'm trying to create a correlation-matrix-like data frame from `df` of the kind `DataFrame.corr` would give me.
I tried

```
corr = df.pivot_table(columns='y',index='x')
y    A    B
x          
A  1.0  0.5
B  0.5  1.0
```

but I don't know how to get rid of the multi-index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need specifying `values` to get rid of multiindex

```
corr = df.pivot_table(columns='y',index='x', values='c')

Out[41]:
y    A    B
x
A  1.0  0.5
B  0.5  1.0
```

If you also want to get rid of axis name, chain `rename_axis`

```
corr = (df.pivot_table(columns='y',index='x', values='c')
          .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

Out[43]:
     A    B
A  1.0  0.5
B  0.5  1.0
```